# What requirements are needed to satisfy UserManager dependencies in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Due to a number of factors on the project I am required to create an instance of `UserManager` manually, without the use of DI. I am doing so as follows:

```
        var userstore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(_userContext);

        IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser> hasher = new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>();

        var validator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>();
        var validators = new List<UserValidator<ApplicationUser>> { validator };

        var result = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userstore, null, hasher, validators, null, null, null, null, _userLogger);
```

This is done in a helper class, and the `result` is returned to the calling class, my controller.

In my controller I make the following call:

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
```

...however, `user` is always null.  I am assuming that some of the `nulls` I'm passing in to the `UserManager` constructor need to be filled in, but I'm only guessing. I actually got the basis for this code from another SO questions that I'm having trouble locating right now.

I don't think there's any magic in what I'm doing to configure some of the other dependencies. I use a `DbContext` called `ApplicationDbContext` that looks like so:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{


    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {   }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

I wire it up in `Startup.cs` as such:

```
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityConnection")));
```

And I have an `AppliactionUser` that comes in from a shared project.

When I do a:

```
var users = userManager.Users.ToList();
```

I get a list of all the expected users.

Why does the call to `GetUserAsync` return `null`?

**Edit & Update**

I just wanted to clarify that I am indeed using DI throughout the project, I just can't use it for `UserManager`. The reason is that the dependencies are typically wired up for it through the `.AddIdentity()` call, which we're not using on this project. Adding the default identity services trumps the OIDC configuration we're using, adds middleware we aren't using and prevents the user from properly authenticating.

The `UserManager` is indeed the normal ASP.NET Core one. But the difference is that we're using OIDC to log the user in.

Comment: Is this the standard `UserManager` from AspNet Identity?  I'm asking, because the only constructor I see listed on MSDN is `UserManager<TUser, TKey>(IUserStore<TUser, TKey>)`, which only has a single argument, and has 2 generic types instead of just 1.

Comment: How did you obtain `_userContext` in your first code snippet? Also, you *could* mention why you cannot use DI

Comment: @BradleyUffner How about [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-2.0)

Comment: @IvanStoev Ahh, I didn't notice that he was using .net core.

Comment: Only [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Core/UserManager.cs#L66) will tell you the truth

Comment: *“Due to a number of factors […] without the use of DI”* – You’re very likely doing it wrong then. Avoiding dependency injection *is a very hard thing* to do in ASP.NET Core, and I would definitely suggest you to try to look at it from another perspective again. Why do you believe that you cannot use dependency injection? What is your actual problem why you cannot use it? Unless this is for a test, you *should* use dependency injection. – Right now, this is a very clear [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/141542).

Comment: @poke I'm indeed using DI and quite extensively, but as noted in the question, I am unable to use it for UserManager. More specifically, I am unable to use it with the typical approach.

Comment: @trailmax thank you for prompting me to do this, I went down the rabbit hole and it lead me to a solution.

Comment: @MisterJames nice one! Glad that helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ApplicationUser` was being returned as `null` because the expected claims were not present on the authenticated user. The `UserManager` is wired up correctly, save a config change that allows the user to be resolved by a differently named claim.

We are using IdentityServer 4 as the backing identity provider on the project. The claim type that identifies the user is called `sub`, which is not normally inspected by the `UserManager`.

In the end, I created a quick class (which I'll likely be able to refactor out to something inline) that looks like so:

```
public class OptionsProvider : IOptions<IdentityOptions>
{
    public IdentityOptions Value { get
        {
            var result = new IdentityOptions();
            result.ClaimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentityOptions { UserIdClaimType = "sub" };
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Next I updated the instantiation of the `UserManager` to include the options:

```
var result = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(
    userstore, 
    new OptionsProvider(), 
    hasher, 
    validators, 
    null, null, null, null, 
    _userLogger);
```

This did the trick.  Thanks again to [@trailmax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/809357/trailmax) for pointing me at the source, which I should admittedly do a little more often.